# In the beginning, the script worked fine but it's getting slow with time as the number of rows is increasing

Tags: google-sheets-api

In the beginning, the script worked fine but it's getting slow with time as the number of rows is increasing.
Is there a way to optimize it or should I use some other tool?

---

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Confidential- 1");
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
var makes = datass.getRange(1,1,1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

if(makeIndex != 0){
var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
}
}
}
```

---

Comment: How do you execute your script?

Comment: @Tanaike I have 2 sheets, one with the data, the other where this needs to be implemented. I am using the script editor to execute the script on that particular spreadsheet only.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I am using the script editor to execute the script on that particular spreadsheet only.`, in your situation, although you are using `onEdit` function, you directly execute the function of `onEdit` with the script editor. And, you don't use your function of `onEdit` as the simple trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike no, it's for conditional dropdown, so, onEdit is being used once the cell value is changed to get the list accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.